# AndroidStudio how to import inner class directly

Tags: android, import, package

Say I have a package `p` that contains the following class:

```
class A {
  // ...

  public static class B { /* ... */ }
}
```

Now, when I use class B in another package Android will give me the option to automatically import it via `Alt+Enter`. However, it will only import class `A`and the usage of `B` in the code will look like this: `A.B`.

I don't like this. I also don't want to manually alter the import statement [`import p.A` to `import p.A.B`] everytime I import class `B`.

How can I change this so that AndroidStudio will always `import p.A.B` whenever I use `B`?

Edit: It doesn't look like it's doable in `Settings->Editor->General->Auto Import`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way

go to `Settings > Code Style > Java > Imports and mark the Insert imports for inner classes checkbox`.